# how do you find error in a SWF?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i feel stupid asking that question, but it seems like i'm unable to find out.

i have a SWF that works perfectly inside flash. once i export as SWF, it doesn't work anymore.

i can't use "trace"

i have tryed that function but it doesn't trigger it for some reason. :

```
function quikTrace(string:String){

    //INIT VARIABLES
    var tmpTxtField:TextField;

    //TEXTFIELD PROPERTIES
    tmpTxtField = new TextField();
    tmpTxtField.text = string;
    tmpTxtField.x = stage.width / 2;
    tmpTxtField.textColor = 0xFFFFFF; //white (black background)
    tmpTxtField.y = stage.height / 2;
    addChild(tmpTxtField);
}
```

is there any "outside the box" way to find errors in a SWF?

Comment: http://labs.findsubstance.com/2008/02/26/firebugs-console-log-flash-debugging-made-easy/ ...   https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashfirebug/   ...   http://code.google.com/p/flash-tracer/ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view trace statements in the browser by doing a few quick steps:

1. Get a debug flash player for your browser. [link](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html)
2. Set up mm.cfg to enable flash logging to a file. [link](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/26/debugging-flex-applications-with-mmcfg-and-flashlogtxt/)
3. Get a text editor / "tail" viewer and read the flashlog.txt file that is generated. This is where FireBug & Flashbug come in handy, if you're in firefox. You can also try baretail for PC, or regular old "tail -f" on a mac/linux machine.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a stupid question at all! You're just learning how to debug Flash for the first time. You can use "trace" with an exported SWF by doing a debug/test build from Flash IDE or Flash Develop. You can then read these traces with Firefox by using the extentions Firebug combined with the Flashbug extension. Now you're all set for getting feedback using traces.

For this particular problem, it's hard to say. Is this function inside of a class or timeline code? If it's a class, it probably because Stage is not ready yet. You can use the event Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE to know when the Stage reference is ready to be used.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Install a debug version of flash player for your browser. It will tell you exactly which line of code is throwing error.

http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html